# How can I make a semi ellipse in Canvas in Python?

Tags: python, canvas

I am trying to make a semi ellipse which would be easy just by using arc. However, the semi ellipse has to have no visible diameter. I mean it should not look like this:
[This is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VStIv.png)

It should look like this:
[The input should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFDg2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use style parameter:

```
coord = 10, 50, 240, 210
arc = canvas.create_arc(coord, start=30, extent=120, style=tk.ARC, width=3)
```